Python logging - AWS Lambda
The code running on AWS Lambda prints the logs properly on Cloudwatch using the logging library.
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info(f'Some log')

But, I'm also using a private third party library, and from that I don't get the printed logs.
How does the setup has to be in the library and in the lambda code in order to print the library's logs?

Rather than using multi-level logging with getLogger(), try this simpler version instead:
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('Some log')

You can always test the code on your own computer before running it in AWS Lambda. The output will be the same.
